# c++ template class's operators

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, matrix, operator-overloading

I'm teaching myself c++ by creating my own data structure class (a matrix, to be exact) and I've changed it to a template class of type `<T>` from only using doubles. The overloaded matrix operators were pretty standard

```
    // A snippet of code from when this matrix wasn't a template class
    // Assignment
    Matrix& operator=( const Matrix& other );

    // Compound assignment
    Matrix& operator+=( const Matrix& other ); // matrix addition
    Matrix& operator-=( const Matrix& other ); // matrix subtracton
    Matrix& operator&=( const Matrix& other ); // elem by elem product
    Matrix& operator*=( const Matrix& other ); // matrix product

    // Binary, defined in terms of compound
    Matrix& operator+( const Matrix& other ) const; // matrix addition
    Matrix& operator-( const Matrix& other ) const; // matrix subtracton
    Matrix& operator&( const Matrix& other ) const; // elem by elem product
    Matrix& operator*( const Matrix& other ) const; // matrix product

    // examples of += and +, others similar
    Matrix& Matrix::operator+=( const Matrix& rhs )
    {
        for( unsigned int i = 0; i < getCols()*getRows(); i++ )
        {
            this->elements.at(i) += rhs.elements.at(i);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Matrix& Matrix::operator+( const Matrix& rhs ) const
    {
        return Matrix(*this) += rhs;
    }
```

But now that Matrix can have a type, I'm having trouble determining which of the matrix references should be type `<T>` and what the consequences would be. Should I allow dissimilar types operate on each other (eg., Matrix`<foo>` a + Matrix`<bar>` b is valid)? I'm also a little fuzzy on how

One reason I'm interested in dissimilar types is to facilitate the use of complex numbers in the future. I'm a newbie at c++ but am happy to dive in over my head to learn. If you're familiar with any free online resources that deal with this problem I would find that most helpful.

Edit: no wonder no one thought this made sense all of my angle brackets in the body were treated as tags! I can't figure out how to escape them, so I'll inline code them.

Comment: You "escape" them by making your code obviously C++ code, by starting with the `template<...` line.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that's not the case. The angle brackets I'm talking about were in the normal, textual body of the question.

Comment: Oh, that. I guess it's being clever. Normally, you use backquotes (over on your ~ key) around things like code or variable names to make them `monospaced`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure that I should illustrate my comment about parameterizing matrix dimensions, since you might not have seen this technique before.

```
template<class T, size_t NRows, size_t NCols>
class Matrix
{public:
    Matrix() {} // `data` gets its default constructor, which for simple types
                // like `float` means uninitialized, just like C.
    Matrix(const T& initialValue)
    {   // extra braces omitted for brevity.
        for(size_t i = 0; i < NRows; ++i)
            for(size_t j = 0; j < NCols; ++j)
                data[i][j] = initialValue;
    }
    template<class U>
    Matrix(const Matrix<U, NRows, NCols>& original)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < NRows; ++i)
            for(size_t j = 0; j < NCols; ++j)
                data[i][j] = T(original.data[i][j]);
    }

private:
    T data[NRows][NCols];

public:
    // Matrix copy -- ONLY valid if dimensions match, else compile error.
    template<class U>
    const Matrix<T, NRows, NCols>& (const Matrix<U, NRows, NCols>& original)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < NRows; ++i)
            for(size_t j = 0; j < NCols; ++j)
                data[i][j] = T(original.data[i][j]);
        return *this;
    }

    // Feel the magic: Matrix multiply only compiles if all dimensions
    // are correct.
    template<class U, size_t NOutCols>
    Matrix<T, NRows, NOutCols> Matrix::operator*(
        const Matrix<T, NCols, NOutCols>& rhs ) const
    {
        Matrix<T, NRows, NOutCols> result;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < NRows; ++i)
            for(size_t j = 0; j < NOutCols; ++j)
            {
                T x = data[i][0] * T(original.data[0][j]);
                for(size_t k = 1; k < NCols; ++k)
                    x += data[i][k] * T(original.data[k][j]);
                result[i][j] = x;
            }
        return result;
    }

};
```

So you'd declare a 2x4 matrix of `float`s, initialized to 1.0, as:

```
Matrix<float, 2, 4> testArray(1.0);
```

Note that there is no requirement for the storage to be on the heap (i.e. using `operator new`) since the size is fixed. You could allocate this on the stack.

You can create another couple matrices of `int`s:

```
Matrix<int, 2, 4> testArrayIntA(2);
Matrix<int, 4, 2> testArrayIntB(100);
```

For copying, dimensions must match though types do not:

```
Matrix<float, 2, 4> testArray2(testArrayIntA); // works
Matrix<float, 2, 4> testArray3(testArrayIntB); // compile error
// No implementation for mismatched dimensions.

testArray = testArrayIntA; // works
testArray = testArrayIntB; // compile error, same reason
```

Multiplication must have the right dimensions:

```
Matrix<float, 2, 2> testArrayMult(testArray * testArrayIntB); // works
Matrix<float, 4, 4> testArrayMult2(testArray * testArrayIntB); // compile error
Matrix<float, 4, 4> testArrayMult2(testArrayIntB * testArray); // works
```

Note that, if there's a botch, **it is caught at compile time.** This is only possible if the matrix dimensions are fixed at compile time, though. Also note that this bounds checking results in *no additional runtime code.* It's the same code that you'd get if you just made the dimensions constant.

**Resizing**

If you don't know your matrix dimensions at compile time, but must wait until runtime, this code may not be of much use.  You'll have to write a class that internally stores the dimensions and a pointer to the actual data, and it will need to do everything at runtime. Hint: write your `operator []` to treat the matrix as a reshaped 1xN or Nx1 vector, and use `operator ()` to perform multiple-index accesses. This is because `operator []` can only take one parameter, but `operator ()` has no such limit. It's easy to shoot yourself in the foot (force the optimizer to give up, at least) by trying to support a `M[x][y]` syntax.

That said, if there's some kind of standard matrix resizing that you do to resize one `Matrix` into another, *given that all dimensions are known at compile time*, then you could write a function to do the resize. For example, this template function will reshape any `Matrix` into a column vector:

```
template<class T, size_t NRows, size_t NCols>
Matrix<T, NRows * NCols, 1> column_vector(const Matrix<T, NRows, NCols>& original)
{   Matrix<T, NRows * NCols, 1> result;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < NRows; ++i)
        for(size_t j = 0; j < NCols; ++j)
            result.data[i * NCols + j][0] = original.data[i][j];

    // Or use the following if you want to be sure things are really optimized.
    /*for(size_t i = 0; i < NRows * NCols; ++i)
        static_cast<T*>(result.data)[i] = static_cast<T*>(original.data)[i];
    */
    // (It could be reinterpret_cast instead of static_cast. I haven't tested
    // this. Note that the optimizer may be smart enough to generate the same
    // code for both versions. Test yours to be sure; if they generate the
    // same code, prefer the more legible earlier version.)

    return result;
}
```

... well, I *think* that's a column vector, anyway. Hope it's obvious how to fix it if not. Anyway, the optimizer will see that you're returning `result` and remove the extra copy operations, basically constructing the result right where the caller wants to see it.

**Compile-Time Dimension Sanity Check**

Say we want the compiler to stop if a dimension is `0` (normally resulting in an empty `Matrix`). There's a trick I've heard called "Compile-Time Assertion" which uses template specialization and is declared as:

```
template<bool Test> struct compiler_assert;
template<> struct compiler_assert<true> {};
```

What this does is let you write code such as:

```
private:
    static const compiler_assert<(NRows > 0)> test_row_count;
    static const compiler_assert<(NCols > 0)> test_col_count;
```

The basic idea is that, if the condition is `true`, the template turns into an empty `struct` that nobody uses and gets silently discarded. But if it's `false`, the compiler can't find a *definition* for `struct compiler_assert<false>` (just a *declaration*, which isn't enough) and errors out.

Better is Andrei Alexandrescu's version (from [his book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315)), which lets you use the declared name of the assertion object as an impromptu error message:

```
template<bool> struct CompileTimeChecker
{ CompileTimeChecker(...); };
template<> struct CompileTimeChecker<false> {};
#define STATIC_CHECK(expr, msg) { class ERROR_##msg {}; \
    (void)sizeof(CompileTimeChecker<(expr)>(ERROR_##msg())); }
```

What you fill in for `msg` has to be a valid identifier (letters, numbers, and underscores only), but that's no big deal. Then we just replace the default constructor with:

```
Matrix()
{   // `data` gets its default constructor, which for simple types
    // like `float` means uninitialized, just like C.
    STATIC_CHECK(NRows > 0, NRows_Is_Zero);
    STATIC_CHECK(NCols > 0, NCols_Is_Zero);
}
```

And voila, the compiler stops if we mistakenly set one of the dimensions to `0`. For how it works, see page 25 of [Andrei's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315). Note that in the `true` case, the generated code gets discarded so long as the test has no side effects, so there's no bloat.

Comment: Thanks very much for the well written example. I had never seen that before. Just wondering, does that make it impossible to resize a Matrix? Or do you just need to use some C++ foo that I don't know about?

Comment: It means that a given *instantiation* of a `Matrix` has a fixed size. That's the price you pay for getting the compiler to do your optimization. BTW, there's a feature called "template specialization" that would let you write code to be used in certain versions of this template. For example, if you had optimized assembly code (e.g. SSE3) for 4x4 `float` matrices, you can get the compiler to substitute in that code for instances of `Matrix<float, 4, 4>`. Otherwise, it will use the above template code. It's pretty versatile.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

But I would point out that your operator declarations are incorrect and/or incomplete.

Firstly, the assignment operator should return the same type as its parameter; viz:

> const Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& src);

Secondly, binary operators return ***a new object***, so you can't return a reference. All binary operators should be declared thus:

```
Matrix operator+( const Matrix& other ) const; // matrix addition
Matrix operator-( const Matrix& other ) const; // matrix subtracton
Matrix operator&( const Matrix& other ) const; // elem by elem product
Matrix operator*( const Matrix& other ) const; // matrix product
```

Actually, it is considered better style to declare and implement binary operators as global friend functions instead:

```
class Matrix { ... };

inline Matrix operator+(const Matrix& lhs,const Matrix& rhs)
{ return Matrix(lhs)+=rhs; }
```

Hope this helps.

---

Now I understand what you're asking.

Presumably your implementation of various operators will in this case consist of operations on the composite types.  So really the question of whether Matrix op Matrix is meaningful depends on whether string op int is meaningful (and whether such a thing might be useful).  You would also need to determine what the return type might be.

Assuming the return type is the same as the LHS operand, the declarations would look something like:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
    template <typename U>
    Matrix<T>&  operator+=(const Matrix<U>& rhs);
};

template <typename T,typename U>
Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T>& lhs,const Matrix<U>& rhs)
{ return Matrix<T>(lhs)+=rhs; }
```

Comment: `const Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& src);` will work, but returning a non-const reference is the generally accepted assignment operator.  For an example, check out [SGI's string implementation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html)

Comment: Oops, copy-paste betrayed me; I realize that binaries don't return a ref. What I was wondering is how allowing a variable type will affect the operators. For instance, what if someone made a Matrix<String> and tried to add a Matrix<int>? Should I try to stop that by having Matrix<T> operator+( const Matrix<T>& other)?

Answer (score 1):

```
Matrix<double> x = ...;
Matrix<int> y = ...;
cout << x + y << endl; // prints a Matrix<double>?
```

OK, that's doable, but the problem gets tricky quickly.

```
Matrix<double> x = ...
Matrix<complex<float>> y = ...
cout << x + y << endl; // Matrix<complex<double>>?
```

You will most likely be happiest if you require that your binary operators use like-type operands and force your application builders to explicitly type-cast their values. For the latter case:

```
cout << ((Matrix<complex<double>>) x) + ((Matrix<complex<double>>) y) << endl;
```

You can provide a member template constructor (or a type conversion operator) to support the conversions.

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
   ...
public:
   template <typename U>
   Matrix(const Matrix<U>& that) { 
       // initialize this by performing U->T conversions for each element in that
   }
   ...
};
```

The alternative, having your binary operator template deduce the correct Matrix return type based on the element types of the two operands, requires some moderately complex template meta-programming, probably not what you're looking to get into.

Comment: And changing the operators to look like this: Matrix<T>& operator+=( const Matrix<T>& other ); Will do the trick?

Comment: @user: I think it's better that the conversion constructor be `explicit` and that the user invokes the conversion constructor instead of casting. For example: `cout << Matrix< complex<double> >(x) + Matrix< complex<double> >(y) << endl;` Allow implicit conversions can lead to bugs that are insidiously difficult to track down.

Comment: ...That's why I think the language should have been designed so that constructors are explicit by default, and that you be required to add an `implicit` keyword to allow implicit conversions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the copy assignment operator should not have `const Matrix&` as its return type; your interface is correct.

Grant's suggestion of how binary operators are implemented is the generally accepted way of doing these things.

It's a nice exercise, but one quickly sees why doing linear algebra in C++ is a bad idea to begin with. Operations like `A+B` and `A*B` are valid only if the dimensions of the matrices match up.

Comment: I don't know why bounds checking is a big deal. It's not that hard to implement.

Comment: Bounds checking, like thread safety, is best implemented via policy classes. Further, if the dimensions are set at compile time via template parameters, instead of being left to runtime as in `std::vector`, then bounds checking and operator compatibility can be checked at compile time and the resulting object code will be the same performance as if it were hard-coded. It's really pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add much at all, because inside a template, the class name itself refers to the current template parameter. So the following are equivalent:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo
{
  Foo<T> bar(const Foo<T> &);
  Foo bar2(const Foo *);       // same
};
```

So all your operations just go through without change. What you should add is a constructor that converts one matrix type into another:

```
temlate <typename T> class Matrix
{
  template <typename U> Matrix(const Matrix<U> &);  // construct from another matrix
  /*...*/
};
```

Using that conversion constructor, you can mix matrices in your operators, as `Matrix<T>::operator+(Matrix<U>)` will use the conversion to create an argument of type `Matrix<T>`, and then you use your already implemented operator.

In C++11 you can add `static_assert(std::is_convertible<U, T>::value, "Boo");` to your converting constructor to give you a useful compile-time diagnostic if you call it with an incompatible type.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that allowing implicit conversion from another Matrix type would be considered good practice. I think it's better that construction from another Matrix type be `explicit` so that there are no surprises in expressions involving different Matrix types.